# JSON selector class in Python

Tags: python, json, iteration

I've created a simple little class called `JSONSelector` to be able to select relevant data from a JSON object (a `dict` in Python). Here's what I have so far - it's based off of a few SQL statements, NumPy methods, and JavaScript iterating methods:

```
class JSONSelector:
    def __init__(self, json):
        self.json = json

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}({})".format(type(self).__name__, str(self.json))
    __repr__ = __str__

    def select(self, selectors):
        if selectors == "*":
            return type(self)(self.json)
        else:
            temp = {}
            for sel in selectors:
                temp[sel] = self.json.get(sel, None)
            return type(self)(temp)

    def where(self, cond):
        temp = {}
        for key, value in self.json.items():
            if cond(key, value):
                temp[key] = value
        return type(self)(temp)

    def astype(self, type_):
        temp = {}
        for key, value in self.json.items():
            temp[key] = type_(value)
        return JSONSelector(temp)

    def sort(self, **kwargs):
        return type(self)(dict(sorted(self.json.items(), **kwargs)))

    def foreach(self, func):
        for key, value in self.json.items():
            if func(key, value) == False: break

    def print(self, func=None):
        if not func:
            print(self)
            return
        else:
            print(func(self))
            return
```

Here's a test case with an explanation:

```
a = JSONSelector({
    "stuff": 5,
    "seeded": 6,
    "number": "7",
    "more_stuff": 8
})

a.select("*") \  # Select all entries from the dict
    .where(lambda key,value: type(value) is int) \ # Where the value is an integer
    .sort(key=lambda x: x[1]) \ # Sort by the value
    .astype(str) \ # Convert the values to type str
    .foreach(lambda key, value: print(key + ": " + value)) # Loop over all entries
```

I'd like to know if any of my code is redundant, where I can shorten things up, and if anything is incorrect. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Minor, but I'd expand your `foreach` a bit to make it clearer that `func` is a side-effect function that happens to return an indicator. In its current form, it looks like the function is only being run for the purpose of the condition.

Something closer to:

```
def foreach(self, func):
    for key, value in self.json.items():
        should_continue = func(key, value)

        if should_continue == False:
            break
```

If you flipped the logic and had them return when they want to break instead though, you could make it read a little nicer:

```
def foreach(self, func):
    for key, value in self.json.items():
        should_break = func(key, value)

        if should_break:
            break
```

---

I'm not sure there's much benefit to using your `print` method. I believe it's convoluting the simple task of just passing the object to `print`. If the user wants to pass some function before printing, just let them do it.

As an example, what intuitively makes more sense to you?:

```
json.print(str)
```

or

```
print(str(json))
```

Personally, I find the latter to make more sense.

I'll also note, your `return`s in that function aren't necessary. You don't need an early return since the two paths of execution are exclusive from each other, and an implicit `return` happens at the end of the method anyway.

Finally, I don't think negating the condition in `if not func` helps readability. I've read negating conditions makes them generally more difficult to understand, and I agree with that. I avoid negating a condition like that unless I really want a certain order of the bodies for aesthetic purposes. I'd write it as:

```
def print(self, func = None):
    if func:
        print(func(self))

    else:
        print(self)
```

Answer (score 4):

A few notes:

Firstly, I would add some *docstrings* to each function to document what the expected behaviour is.

In `select` when you're not doing any mutations (i.e. under the * case), it seems you could just return `self`. Is there any reason to make a new copy?

In `select`, `where`, `astype` instead of creating a temporary dict, you could use a dict comprehension instead, example:

```
def where(self, cond):
    return type(self)({key: value for key, value in self.json.items() if cond(key, value)})
```

In `astype` you're using `JSONSelector`, however everywhere else you're using `type(self)` this should be consistent whichever one you go for.

`print` seems like an unnecessary function, but if you keep it the `return` lines have no effect.

Hope that's helpful.

Comment: Taking a copy (even without doing mutations) is how Django does things as well - as that way you can mutate one of the results without mutating the copy.

Comment: @Shadow that makes sense and is consistent